# docker for windows run protractor automation

Tags: windows, docker, google-chrome, protractor

I am trying to run protractor e2e on windows docker container and getting below error. The error seems to be related to Windows Media Feature missing. Is there a way to configure windows media feature?
OS Version:                10.0.17763 N/A Build 17763

```
[15:44:45] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:44:45] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[1207/154446.081:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(142)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 0

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50792/devtools/browser/0ebdd350-4af1-4680-a2f7-e5d9d4b47b0a
[1207/154446.222:ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1368)] DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary: mf.dll: The specified module could not be found. (0x7E)
[1207/154446.222:ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1368)] DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary: mfplat.dll: The specified module could not be found. (0x7E)
[1207/154446.237:ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1368)] DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary: msmpeg2vdec.dll: The specified module could not be found. (0x7E)
[1207/154446.237:ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1372)] DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary: dxva2.dll: The specified module could not be found. (0x7E)
[1207/154446.237:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(142)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 0
[1207/154446.237:ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1376)] DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary: msvproc.dll: The specified module could not be found. (0x7E)
[1207/154446.331:ERROR:platform_font_skia.cc(343)] Could not find any font: Segoe UI, sans. Falling back to the default
[15:44:48] W/launcher - Ignoring uncaught error WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Chromium\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=86.0.4240.22 (398b0743353ff36fb1b82468f63a3a93b4e2e89e-refs/branch-heads/4240@{#378}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
```